# How to pass vararg of different classes that inherit another class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

I'm trying to create a simple game in Kotlin. I have a BitmapContainer class which is inherited by another classes.
Inheritors has init block and companion objects which contains list of bitmaps, so that they created once and used for all objets of the same type.

What I want is to create BitmapPreloader class, which has a vararg of BitmapContainer-derived classes and a callback. Preloader should create one instance of every class in vararg and invoke callback method.

The question is: how to pass classes that way? I just can't figure it out.

I don't know if it will be of help, but here's some of described code:

```
abstract class BitmapContainer(
val res: Resources,
val downScale: Float,
val onInitializationCompletedListener: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
protected fun createBitmap(
    @DrawableRes resId: Int,
    useFilter: Boolean = false
): Bitmap {
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId).also {
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            it,
            (it.width / downScale * Screen.ratioX).toInt(),
            (it.height / downScale * Screen.ratioY).toInt(),
            useFilter
        )
    }
}

protected fun createBitmapList(
    resIds: List<Int>,
    useFilter: Boolean = false
): List<Bitmap> = ArrayList<Bitmap>().apply {
    resIds.forEach {
        this.add(createBitmap(it, useFilter))
    }
}
```

BitmapContainer example:

```
class GroundTileBitmapContainer(
res: Resources,
downScale: Float,
listener: (() -> Unit)? = null) : BitmapContainer(res, downScale, listener) {

init {
    if (bitmap == null) {
        bitmap = createBitmap(R.drawable.ground_02)
    }
}

companion object {
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
}
```

}

What I want to do in Preloader:

```
lass BitmapPreloader(
vararg classList: Any?, //That is the line I have no idea how to do
callback: () -> Unit) {

init {
    classList.forEach { it::class.createInstance() }
    callback.invoke()
}
```

Comment: When you type `vararg classList: Any?` means you're explicitly requesting from caller for different object. In that case, you don't need to create objects your self in constructor. If you really want to create it by yourself in `BitmapPreloader` then expect to pass `Class` type as parameter like `vararg classList: Class<*>?` and then do it like `classList.forEach { it.createInstance() }`

Comment: If you specify the `classList` vararg type as `Any`, then you would need actual instances of these classes to use, which defeats the purpose because then their constructors will already have been called, so there is no bitmap loading left to be done by the time the function is called. Once these are all loaded, you will have to pass instances around to be drawn. I suggest skipping the companion objects entirely. Create an asset manager class to load a single instance of each bitmap, without needing separate subclasses for each bitmap.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Thank you, Sir! I've never known about the asterisk usage in Kotlin generics, googled it and found out about it and out / in words. Finally I stopped on that constructor:

`class BitmapPreloader(resources: Resources, callback: () -> Unit, classList: List<KClass<out BitmapContainer>>) `

Comment: @Tenfour04 The thing is those bitmap containers contains not a single bitmap objects like in the example, they contain lists of bitmaps for every animation of character (example has only one bitmap because it's static ground tile). So I wanted it to be reusable throught different levels, and companion objects are the only way I could think of to be able to staticly contain all the bitmaps even when objects using those are dead.

Comment: If you have an asset manager class that stores the references to all of the instances of the class(es) that contain bitmaps, then all the other game classes that need to draw them can get their references from the asset manager. The instances with the loaded bitmaps never go away until you explicitly unload them through the asset manager.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I can't find a way to use it in this particullar project because, for instance, I have like 30+ instances of platform tiles + half of that ready to go placed behind the scene. And that list is constantly changed because tiles off screeen are destroyed and new added. But all of them use the same single bitmap. So I need to check them  and remove and add new ones to asset manager on every single update() call which is called every single frame. 
Or may be I misunderstood you? Could you please add some asset manager example code?

Comment: I'm saying instead of using a separate wrapper class for each Bitmap instance, with a companion object reference to the instance, use a single Bitmap wrapper class that is used for all bitmaps, creating a new instance for each unique image. The asset manager class can dole out copies of the *references* to any tiles that need them, so there is never any cleanup to do on tiles. The asset manager would only ever unload a bitmap when you tell it that specific bitmap is no longer used anywhere.